# List comprehension with complex conditions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, list-comprehension

I was looking up for ways to make my loop fast,then I found about list comprehensions.

I tried it on my own, but I don't fully understand it yet.

From what I learned researching about list comprehensions, the code I like to execute would be on the left side, followed by the conditions then the for loop.

So, it would basically look like this.

```
["Something I'd like to execute" Some conditions for loop]
Following this style, I did it like this.
```

The code I was trying to turn into a one liner:

```
graph = []

for g in range(M):
    satisfy = []
    graph_count = 0
    for i in range(N-1):
        count = 0
        for j in range(N):
            if i < j and count < 1:
                if graph_count < g:
                    count += 1
                    graph_count += 1
                    satisfy.append("1")
                else:
                    satisfy.append("0")
            elif i < j:
                satisfy.append("0")
    graph.append("".join(map(str,satisfy)))
```

My Attempt

```
graph = [[count+=1,graph_count+=1,satisfy.append("1") if graph_count < g else satisfy.append("0") and if i<j and count<1 else satisfy.append("0") if i<j for j in range(N) count=0 for i in range(N-1)] graph_count=0, "".join(map(str,satisfy)) for g in range(M)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use side effect expressions like `count+=1` in comprehensions or `append`. Well you can sometimes but that's not the spirit... Looks like you're making the syntax up...

Comment: also, not all codes can be turned to one-liners

Comment: This is a good example of when not to use a list comprehension.

Comment: list comprehensions can use tests but only with _ternary expressions_. You have to see them as a flow where there's one input and one output, with conditions to include the output and conditions to transform it

Comment: `for j in range(N):
            if i < j ` ... better just do `for j in range(i+1,N)` and drop the test...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I see. I didn't know about the restrictions, and I really thought any code can be turned into one-liner. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of optimization:

- micro-optimization (statement level, e.g. f-strings are faster than `format` function)
- macro optimization (algorithm, used data structures, etc)

Optimizing algorithms may have much higher returns than spending the same effort on micro-optimizations.

Here is my solution to your problem. After analyzing the expected output, I found some patterns and reduced the number of loops and allocations:

```
from itertools import accumulate

graph = []
size = N * (N - 1) // 2
s = list(reversed(list(accumulate(range(N)))))
for g in range(M):
    satisfy = ["0"] * size
    for i in range(N - 1):
        if g > i:
            satisfy[size - s[i]] = "1"

    graph.append("".join(satisfy))
```